# Как разобраться со знаками препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться со знаками препинания. Предложение такого типа:
*-Читал(?) и там уже вранье пишут!*
Вопросительным словом тут является "читал", но после него предложение продолжается, и оно уже повествовательное. Разбивать его на два: "Читал? И так уже..." тоже не вижу смысла - все-таки оно является цельной смысловой конструкцией ("читал" без остального пояснения будет бессмыслицей). Или же все-таки единственный выход - разбить фразу на два предложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, придется разбить высказывание на два предложения. Повествовательная и вопросительная части могут составлять одно предложение, но при этом вопросительная часть следует после повествовательной, то есть знак вопроса, в также повышение тона, возможны только в конце предложения.

Что касается слова "читал", то оно по смыслу должно быть связано с предыдущим содержанием.

В то же время, как вариант, можно применить авторское оформление: "Читал? - и там уже вранье пишут". Но это будет отклонение от современной нормы.

ИМЕЕТСЯ ПРАВИЛО

http://www.telenir.net/jazykoznanie/pravila_russkoi_orfografii_i_punktuacii_polnyi_akademicheskii_spravochnik/p3.php

1) При смысловом подчеркивании отдельных членов вопросительного или восклицательного предложения знаки препинания ставятся после каждого из членов, которые оформляются как самостоятельная синтаксическая единица, т. е. начинаются с прописной буквы: — Что вас привело к ним? — неожиданно бытовым, ворчливым голосом спросил он. — Недомыслие? Страх? Голод? (А. Т.);

2) Однако прописные буквы заменяются строчными, если перед перечислением стоят знаки двоеточие или тире (впереди имеется обобщение): Всё отвергал: законы!совесть! веру! (Тр.); Она спросила, кто он, не француз ли, и стала по его просьбе гадать: бельгиец? датчанин? голландец? (Наб.); Вот так играть свою игру — шутя! всерьез! до слез! навеки! не лукавя! — как он играл, как, молоко лакая, играет с миром зверь или дитя (Ахмад.).

3) В других случаях (при отсутствии знаков двоеточия или тире перед перечислением) подобные написания со строчной буквой не соответствуют современной пунктуационной норме, например: Зачем же здесь? и в этот час? (Гр.); Что мне делать? просить прощения? хорошо, да в чем? (П.).

4)Вопросительный и восклицательный знаки ставятся внутри предложения, если они относятся к вставным конструкциям : Девчушка (как же ее звали?) шла по улице, как по своей жизни (Мак.);

Answer (score 1):

София права, можно применить авторские знаки препинания. Но все же, на мой взгляд, здесь, скорее всего, риторический вопрос.Поэтому я бы оформил так: Читал, и там уже вранье пишут***?!***